# RewriteRule on file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site with over 800 pages and need to pretty up the URLS. I need to go from this:

http://www.name-of-site.co.uk/services/plumbing?f=franchise

to this:

http://www.name-of-site.co.uk/franchise/plumbing

I have managed to do this with this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/plumbing$ /services/plumbing.php?f=$1 [L]
```

This thing is, there are hundreds more of these and I don't want to have an entry for every page. Is there a way I can do it with reg ex's or wildcards or variables?

Not the best with htaccess so any help would be wonderful.

Thank you and regards.

Comment: Yes, it is possible! You just need to generalize your regex a little more.

Comment: Thank you Alan. Still much to learn with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /services/$2.php?f=$1 [L]
```

So if you go to:

```
http://example.com/franchise/plumbing
```

it'll rewrite to: `/services/plumbing.php?f=franchise`

and if you go to:

```
http://example.com/something/another-page
```

it'll rewrite to: `/services/another-page.php?f=something`

Comment: Jon - That is perfect and worked a treat. Thank you so much.